# Testing iPhone 5 (4") apps on iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad, iphone-5

I was hoping to be able to test iPhone 5 (4") apps on the iPad 3 in its emulator mode.

To indicate it's an iPhone 5 app I've added the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image and in the simulator it works as expected.

When I try to run it on the iPad however only the 3.5" version is shown in its iPhone emulator.

Does the iPad not yet support the 4" mode or do I need to enable something else? (iOS 6 GM seed)

Comment: ask this on the apple dev. forums

Comment: Any movement on this with iOS7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the iPad can't support the 4" iPhone mode because the display would be too small for 2x (zoomed).